# Test Web API using Advance Rest Client(GET) when Parameter type is Class

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, advanced-rest-client

I want to Call API method(GET Request) 
GetInfo(Request request),
This Request class has 2 parameters,

```
public class Request
    {

        public int MachineId;
        public int PackageId;

    }
```

I know if i have Parameters of type int/string in API method, i would call it as http://localhost/Service/api/Info/GetInfo?MachineId=1&PackageId=1,
I am not sure how to add Request parameters to my URL in this case.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Did you tried same approach?

Comment: Yes i did, request is null when i hit break point at my Api method GetInfo(Request request).

Comment: Did you tried it with `[FromQuery]` attribute for the request argument?

Comment: Please share `definition` of your function in `controller`.

Comment: can you share the code for your function call?